# MEAN.JS -- Request objects, Express controllers, and Mongoose Schemas

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, mean-stack

I have created a Mongoose connection manager to manage a unique connection per user in my application. At the time that a user logs in, I create a new connection to a custom database URI that is unique to that user. I name the connection so that it can be retrieved (looked up) later. Example invocation:

```
var myConnection = require('connection-manager').createConnection(user._id);
```

As you can see here, I name my connections after an _id property of a user object. Easy enough. I can then look up my unique connection for this user using:

```
var myConnection = require('connection-manager').getConnection(user._id);
```

The only difference between those two methods is that one creates and returns the new connection and the other (the getConnection() method) does a simple look up in the pool of current connections and returns the connection object that matches our passed name (user._id).

Here's where I'm running into problems. In my server controllers, I normally do this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
    Foo = mongoose.model('Foo');
```

This is really straight forward. I'm loading the model, 'Foo', that has been registered with the default Mongoose connection. This is handy because all methods of my controller can simply invoke this model by doing something like:

```
exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    myFoo = new Foo({whatever: whatever});
};
```

This works because Foo was declared and loaded at the start of the file. But now that I'm moving to a connection manager, I need to be able to do something like this in my controller file:

```
'use strict';

var manager = require('connection-manager').getConnection(user._id),
    Foo = manager.model('Foo');

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    var myFoo = new Foo({whatever: whatever});
};
```

The problem is that the request object that gets passed to exports.create() is where the user._id is that I need in order to look up my custom connection in the connection manager. How do I work around this..?

Comment: *"But what if I wanted to access that request object outside of create()?"* Please give us an example, as this makes no sense. Accessing it outside of create() wouldn't be too useful..

Comment: I completely rewrote my post to be more specific. Please let me know if this doesn't make sense and I'll clarify as best as I can :) Thanks for the patience.

Comment: You need to "get" the connection on each request. getting a connection outside of the create for a specific user doesn't make sense, because multiple users using this app will all be using that same file, at the same time.

Comment: Can you be a tad bit more specific on that? I was thinking about middleware to handle that but I'm still not exactly sure how that works.

Comment: Kinda hard to explain here in a comment, i'll just post an answer.

Comment: Kevin B: my favorite guy on SE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have in your question that gets a connection for the create method only runs once, the first time you require that file. That is why it doesn't make sense to use the userid at that point, because there is no user at that point, the server might not even be accepting request at that point. Instead, you need to get the connection on each request, meaning, inside the create method.

```
'use strict';

var manager = require('connection-manager');

exports.create = function(req, res, next) {
    var connection = manager.getConnection(req.user._id),
        Foo = connection.model('Foo'),
        myFoo = new Foo({whatever: whatever});
};
```

Comment: Hah! Interestingly enough, this is currently what I have. But it feels really crappy to me because now I have to do a getConnection() and load the model on each of the methods that belong to my controller. Where I used to do it just once, now I have to do it many places.

Comment: well, you could do all of that up front in the manager if you wanted and store a collection of models on the connection that is returned, though that would be difficult to maintain.

Comment: I thought about that, too. I think for the time I'll leave it be. Thank you so much for the help. I really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In your code above:

```
app.route('/someroute').post(foo.create);
```

It pipes the request directly to foo.create, which is kinda confusing for beginners, what it really means is:

```
app.post('/someroute', function(req, res, next) {
    //get your data here
    //user = req.user_id;
    foo.create(req, res, next);
});
```

My suggestion is, don't use MEAN stack to begin with, create a simple express application and figure out how the routes works.

And use **[express.Router()](http://expressjs.com/api.html#router)** instead of **app.route**.

Thanks.

Comment: I appreciate your reply but unfortunately it doesn't apply much to my updated post. I completely rewrote it to clarify on exactly my problem -- I wish I would have been faster so you wouldn't have wasted your time :(